# Spring Cloud Config Server plain text

Tags: java, spring-cloud

I've been looking into Spring Cloud Config Server but I am unable to get plain text files returned as I expect. The overview here http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_serving_plain_text describes the ability to serve the actual file content via and endpoint:

`/foo/default/master/nginx.conf`

but I'm not able to get this to work. In my Spring Server config I have:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: ssh://xxxxxxxx/cloudconfig.git
          cloneOnStart: true
          searchPaths: test
```

and in my cloudconfig repo I have 2 files (both called simple.conf), one in the root and one in /test directory so I assume I should just be able to hit the URL

http://localhost:8888/test/default/master/simple.conf

and get the contents of the simple.conf file, but I'm getting a 404 for every combination I've tried.

I'm using 1.0.4.RELEASE version

Is there a working example of this or have I misunderstood the usage?

Comment: I believe that is a new feature and only available in 1.1.0.x

Comment: Also you'd need the full /app/profile/label in the path (I assume "test" is the search path in this example).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated to 1.1.0.M5 and all looks good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments from Spencer, the version I was using did not support this so used 1.1.0.M5 solved this for me.