# Spring cloud's config server plain text api with SVN and a default label

Tags: spring, spring-boot, svn, spring-cloud, configserver

I have spring boot 2 app that acts as a config server with the following properties. Notice in particularly the "default-label" properties which is the empty string because we check out directly the folder that contains the files, and not some parent branch/folder.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  profiles:
    include: subversion
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        svn:
          uri: https://...somesvnrepo.../project/trunk/config
          username: fake
          password: notreal
          default-label:
          basedir: C:\Users\John\Documents\Application\configserver_tmp
```

The contents of /trunk/config is straigthforward. There ae no subdirectories and just these files:

- application.yml
- application-dev.yml
- myservice.yml
- myservice-dev.yml
- logback.xml

Serving the yml files works fine, but getting the logback.xml file using the "[plain text api](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__serving_plain_text.html)" not work at all.

Doing `localhost:8888/appname/default/master/logback.xml` gives the error "no label master found" which is true, I don't have that label. Any other combination of paths by omitting profiles or labels results in a 404 all the way up to just calling `localhost:8888/logback.xml`. Adding the ?useDefaultLabel request parameter makes no difference. Actually I don't understand the purpose of the appname, profile and label part of the url when the context is to get a plain text file that is not bound to any specific application, profile or label.

I found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355940/spring-cloud-config-server-plain-text) on the internet but they mention updating their spring boot version and then it worked for them. I'm already at the latest spring boot version (2.1.3-release).

Is this because I use SVN? Or because of of the default-label being empty?

Comment: It is very clear that no label master is present. Define the label as part of ```spring.cloud.config.label``` in the config client application.

Comment: @Barath Define it to what value? What is the concept of a label when regards to SVN when I don't use subdirectories? 
Also, I'm not using a client app to test this, I'm just using the browser and typing the urls manually (to mimic what an application would do) but not any combination of urls I tried yields a resut for serving plain text

Comment: Labels are branches. Mention the branch/trunk name accordingly. Share the URLs you tried and share the branch names let's see.